# Can not connect to Ghostdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I wish to extract some information from a dynamic website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/Users/xxx/anaconda/phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/bin/phantomjs')
driver.get("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/javascript/ajaxDemo.html")
time.sleep(3)
print(driver.find_element_by_id("content").text)
driver.close()
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error message:

```
"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 
Can not connect to GhostDriver on port 61121"
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4, and the latest Selenium package.

Comment: sudo npm install -g phantomjs

Comment: Thanks sunit. I get sudo: npm: command not found. This is after I've run pip install npm. Should I be installing npm differently, and if so how?

Comment: @runawaykid: Are you running Linux? You can install phantomjs via Linux package manager.

Comment: @Kevin: thanks. I'm running on a Mac OS X El Capitan. What steps should I take?

Comment: https://github.com/eugene1g/phantomjs/releases @runawaykid use this link to download required package

Comment: @Sunit: Thank you so much, that works! Was this something to do with the package on http://phantomjs.org/download.html not being compatible with the latest mac OS?